# How to select more rows with MySQL after sorting?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which have 10 results. Let's say the following:

```
        id      user    number 
        --      ----    ------

        1       user1   10
        2       user2   5
        3       user3   30
        4       user4   45
        5       user5   5
        6       user6   22
        7       user7   10
        8       user8   40
        9       user9   90
        10      user10  65
```

I basically want to sort them, by the 'number' value.

So it should be something like this:

```
        SORT    id      user    number 
        ----    --      ----    ------

        1       2       user2   5 
        2       5       user5   5
        3       1       user1   10
        4       7       user7   10
        5       6       user6   22
        6       3       user3   30
        7       8       user8   40
        8       4       user4   45
        9       10      user10  65
        10      9       user9   90
```

After it's been sorted, I want to select * from (for example) the one with id = 6 (which's number is 22) and 2 other results which is above it (in this case: id = 7 and 1) and 2 other results under it (in this case: id = 3 and 8).

So the return result should be something like this, when I'm searching for id = 6:

```
        SORT    id      user    number 
        ----    --      ----    ------

        3       1       user1   10
        4       7       user7   10
        5       6       user6   22
        6       3       user3   30
        7       8       user8   40
```

I could esaily do this on server side, if I select everything, however there will be a huge data amount in here, so I'd rather just select those, which are appropriate to my search.

Is there any way to do this with MySQL?

Comment: Why you are searching with id after you have sorted out the data with number.

Comment: What result would you expect if there were, in your example, more than two records with number = 10?

Comment: Don't you wish you had `LEAD()` and `LAG()`, or `ROW_NUMBER()` functions in MySQL...?

Comment: @abl The ID's are always different. There should not be a duplicate inthe database.

Comment: @Radical_Activity the id field is unique, but not the number. You could have another record with number = 10 (say, for user11). Then the two (ordered) results above user6 could be (user1, user7), (user7, user1), (user11, user7), (user7, user11) etc. You would not get the same result with each execution of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical way to get what you want:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*
       from table t
       where number <= (select number where id = 6 limit 1)
       order by number desc
       limit 3
      ) union all
      (select t.*
       from table t
       where id > (select number where id = 6 limit 1)
       order by number asc
       limit 2
      )
     ) t
order by number;
```

This assumes that when duplicates appear, you still want 5 rows output.  It also assumes that less than five rows is ok for the first two or last two rows.  An index on `id` would help performance of this query.

Comment: OP wants to order by number, not by id

Answer (score 0):

Get UNION of 2 queries:

1. Get all records <= the desired `number`, in your case 22. Sort them in descending order and get top 3 results.
2. Get all records > the desired `number` in ascending order and get top 2 results
3. Get the `UNION` of these 2 results and order them in ascending order

HTH

EDIT: My idea to post this answer was to give an algorithm on how to approach such queries. Instead of selecting on `number`, you can get all records based on `id` and then UNION them.

Comment: If there are many records with number = 22 this will get you a random selection of 3 of them, which may or may not include the main record (user6 in OP's example)